# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{1+x_n}$ if $x_1>0$ and $ x_{n+1} = x_n ^2 + x_n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Suppose $ x_1\in \Re $ , and let $ x_{n+1} = x_n ^2 + x_n $ for $ n\geq 1 $.

Assuming $ x_1 > 0 $, find

$  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(1+x_n) $.

What can you say about the cases where $ x_1 < 0 $?

Notes: 
Just some help with evaluating the initial recurrence relation would be much appreciated.

By setting $ T_n = x_n + 1/2 $  I obtained the possibly simpler recurrence $ T_{n+1} = T_n^2 + 1/4 $.

Comment: Re "simplicity", note that the recursions $z\to z^2+c$, far from being "simple", have basically opened up a whole new area of sophisticated mathematics (check "Mandelbrot set").

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{x_n}&=\frac{x_n- x_{n+1}}{x_n x_{n+1}}\\
&=\frac{x_n - x_n - x_n^2}{x_n x_{n+1}}\\
&=-\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}\\
&=-\frac{x_n}{x_n+x_n^2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+x_n}
\end{align}